# YouTube Rate (like/dislike) comments, Share, Add To, More

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api

I'm trying to embed YouTube video on website along with complete section having rating(like, dislike),  Share, Add to playlist, More actions and Comments([image]). Embed iframe is providing just video to play .I know we have YouTube data API V3 to build this but is their any existing library/plugin to integrate ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have come up with, try to use the feeds api and get the video data out of it.

my way of doing it is to do a Ajax call to the feeds api.

```
video_id = "kxxnMYwL9XA";                  
 $.ajax({url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + video_id+ "?    v=2&alt=json",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data) { parseresults(data);  }
                });

            function parseresults(data) {
            var title = data.entry.title.$t; 
            var viewcount = data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount;
            var author = data.entry.author[0].name.$t;
            var likes = data.entry.yt$rating.numLikes;

            var dislikes = data.entry.yt$rating.numDislikes;

                     console.log("author: " + author + " | title: " + title +     " | likes: " + likes + " | dislikes: " + dislikes);
                 }
```

the data is retrieved as JSON so you can get any value of your needs out of it.

hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adarsh. My question was on how to implement functionality to rate a video , can comment, provide share options for embeded video. It should be almost replica of actions provided in YouTube. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUUpu.png)

Comment: Oh ok, well this is how to retrieve data but i'm afraid i don't know how to 'post' data to the youtube servers.